# Angular 4 templateUrl not loading MVC view

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to load html from ASP.Net core 2 view controller in an Angular 4.2.5 client app Component.

```
templateUrl: 'navbar/index'
```

I don't get an error in the console and the network monitor in Chrome does not show any traffic.

I am using webpack and I removed the 'angular2-template-loader' from the config.

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' }
```

All of my static templates get loaded as such

```
template: require('./home.component.html')
```

and load fine. As a matter of fact if I replace the MVC call with a static file it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the view appears when you type http://localhost/navbar/index ?
if yes you can try templateUrl: '/navbar/index' . When I encountered the same issue the problem was the mvc route mismatch..

Comment: I got it to work - it forgot to add the route names to the controller. Duh!

Comment: I'm with the same problem, but your solution not working for me. Can you load the mvc view writing the property like templateUrl: '/view/test' for example ?